# Error about deleted bool operator when static_cast to int

Tags: c++, boolean, static-cast

When doing a `static_cast<int>`, I'm getting a complaint about a deleted bool() operator:

```
main.cpp:15:35: error: use of deleted function 'J::operator bool()'
     j = static_cast<int>(*this) + 1;
                               ^
```

Probably something obvious I'm missing here, but I don't see why it would be trying to run the bool conversion:

```
#include <iostream>

struct J {
    int j;
    J (int j) : j (j) {}

    operator bool() = delete;

    explicit operator int() const {
        if (j > 304) { std::cout << "Out of range\n"; }
        return j;
    }

    J& operator++ () {
        j = static_cast<int>(*this) + 1;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    J b {1020};
    ++b;
}
```

Comment: A hunch: what happens if you remove the const qualification?

Comment: @eerorika Ah, yes.  In my actual scenario, missing a const on the bool() operator, actually.  Feel free to answer if you like.

Comment: I'm going afk right now. Feel free to write an answer yourself.

Comment: I'll give someone else a chance in case they feel like doing an actual good job explaining why a non-const method converting to bool outranks a const method converting to int (when you ask to static_cast a non-const object to int).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, changing the bool operator overloads to either one of these:

```cpp
explicit operator bool() = delete; // Prevent implicit conversion (int to bool)
operator bool() const = delete;    // Non-const had higher priority for resolution
```

This is about two things. Implicit integer conversion and function resolution order.

---

It seems like this is basically of typical C++ function resolution. Let's recall that:

```cpp
class A {
public:
  void foo() { cout << "non-const" << endl; }
  void foo() const { cout << "const" << endl; }
};

int main() {
  A a1;
  a1.foo(); // prints "non-const"
  const A a2;
  a2.foo(); // prints "const"
  return 0;
}
```

If non-const one is available, it has higher priority than the const one.

Back to your example, let's make things clear, change the bool cast operator to non-const int cast.

```cpp
explicit operator int() = delete; // Instead of "operator bool() = delete;"
```

With this, it still fails for the same reason with above. As `operator++` is non-const so `this` is non-const so `static_cast<int>(*this)` is resolved to non-const `operator int`. However it is deleted so the compiler complains. So if we did not have this non-const one deleted, the it would have been resolved with const version and work correctly.

So now what about `operator bool() = delete;`? This function is not declared with `explicit` so `int` will implicitly try to convert to `bool`. So it is resolved with the deleted one before getting to the const one.

Comment: Adding const to the operator bool looks more logical